# Remaining character count in text area is not working with Right click and paste in Primefaces

Tags: jquery, primefaces

Key strokes are working fine (Ctrl + V, Shift + insert) while pasting the content in Text area. But Right click and Paste is not reducing the character count.

```html
<p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="30" counter="display" maxlength="10" counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." autoResize="false" styleClass="testClass" />
<h:outputText id="display" />
```

I tried with Jquery event to capture the paste and trigger the keyup event. But no luck. Below is the code i tried.

```
$('.testClass').on('paste', function (e) {
    var id = $(this);
    var temp;
    clearTimeout(temp);
    temp = setTimeout(function() { 
       $(id).keyup();
    }, 200);
});
```

I tried by add the ajax for the text area as well, but its not worked for me.

```
<p:ajax event="keyup"  />
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Use `input` instead of `paste`. Then you can get rid of the ugly `setTimeout()` hack you're using too

Comment: Thanks It worked. i removed the Timeout as well.

Comment: Your title does not match the first line of your post. And what PF version do you use? If it is 6.1, please check for fixes in elite releases and file an enhancement request in GITHUB if even 6.2 from source has this problem. @RoryMcCrossan: please post an answer

Comment: I am using the older version 5.2. Corrected the Title